# quadratic function positive

Tags: quadratics

Put constraints on a quadratic function. I know that for $x > 0$ then $ax^2 + bx + c > 0$

I read around but I just found positive for all $x$. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Your question as it stands, is a little unclear.

Comment: Your statement is wrong. If $x > 0$ then it doesn't hold that $ax^2 + bx + c > 0$. For example choose $a=-1$, $b = 0$, $c = 0$. Then you get clearly get that $ax^2 + bx + c  = -x^2 < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\;a\neq0\;$ and that is then an actual quadratic, then it describes an upwards parabola if $\;a>0\;$ and a downwards one if $\;a<0\;$.

So you want $\;a>0\;$ (first constraint), and then one way to succeed here is to make the parabola **all the time** positive, and that means it has no roots (points where it vanishes), and this is the same as requiring its discriminant to be negative:

$$\Delta=b^2-4ac$$

and then you succeed...and, in fact, $\;ax^2=bx+c>0\;$ **for all** $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ , not only for $\;x>0\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

You want $ax^2+bx+c>0$ for $x>0$.

This require $a>0$ as a first condition ( the parabola must be upward)

Then we have three possibilities:

1) the parabola is always positive ( for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$) if $b^2-4ac<0$ .

2)The parabola has value $0=$ for $x=0$ and is positive for all other values of $x$. This means that $b=c=0$.

3) The parabola has two roots, one for a value $x<0$ and the other for $x=0$: if $c=0$ and $b>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

When $x\to \infty$, $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \to a \implies a>0$

When $x\to 0^{+}$, $f(x)\to c \implies c \geq 0$

Now

> $$\left \{ \begin{align*} a &>0 \\ c &\geq 0 \end{align*} \right.$$

**Case I:** $\Delta=b^2-4ac \geq 0$, the largest root should be non-positive.

> $$\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \leq 0$$
>
> $$0 \leq \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \leq b$$
>
> $$\implies b \geq 2\sqrt{ac}$$

**Case II:** $\Delta=b^2-4ac<0$, $f(x)>0 \; \forall x$

> $$b^2 < 4ac$$
>
> $$\implies -2\sqrt{ac} < b < 2\sqrt{ac}$$
>
> where $ac>0$

**Combining all together:**

> \begin{align*}
>   a &>0 \\
>   c &\geq 0 \\
>   b & \quad
>   \left \{
>     \begin{array}{rcll}
>       \geq & 0 & , & c =0 \\
>       > & -2\sqrt{ac} & , & c>0
>     \end{array}
>   \right.
> \end{align*}